# Irregular shaped clickable area / buttons in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is there a way to make an irregular shaped area / button clickable in Visual Basic?
I've seen some tutorials, but most of them use old .dll files that dont exist anymore uses pngs where the transparent area around is still clickable or loads in some libraries that I'm not sure how to work with.

I have tried substituting irregular shaped buttons for many normal shaped buttons to fill the same area, but this as one can understand is very inconvenient.
My skill level isn't that high, so most of what I've tried does work but is in the same category as my last example.

Comment: Hello, I think you should take a look at this component https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10558/Shape-Control-for-NET since there is not a strait forward solution for this you'll have to learn do DIY or work based on one of those projects with similar goals.

Comment: Instead of `visual-studio`, tag your question with the GUI platform you're actually using, e.g., WPF, WinForms, UWP, some type of Web UI, other. Also, post your best shot at it.

Comment: Check : http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_shaped_button.html

Comment: Hey TheTveit, I know the question is 28 days old, but if you're already into button looks, you can add a push-down effect.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485836/code-for-a-button-that-has-a-push-down-effect-vb-net

Comment: Thank you, I'm not currently working on this since I have some other things to take care of. But I'll look in to it next time I'm on it